# Python: How to loop/itereate list in lists or tuples - special unique output?

Tags: python, list, loops, tuples, iteration

I need help

Here are my lists and tuples. I don't know which one is better for solution, so I print both here.

I show my problem here only using lists.

```
x11 = ["1", "x", "t", "f", "T"]
x12 = ["C", "D", "6"]
x13 = ["5", "9", "J", "D"]
x14 = ["e", "a", "o", "x", "f", "z"]
x15 = ["1", "x", "7", "f", "T"]
x16 = ["D", "O", "0", "B", "8", "Q", "q"]
x17 = ["c", "a"]
x18 = ["9", "J", "7", "f", "I"]
x19 = ["C", "O", "D", "0", "6"]
x20 = ["P", "F", "C"]

xlist1 = [x11,x12,x13,x14,x15,x16,x17,x18,x19,x20]

t11 = ("1", "x", "t", "f", "T")
t12 = ("C", "D", "6")
t13 = ("5", "9", "J", "D")
t14 = ("e", "a", "o", "x", "f", "z")
t15 = ("1", "x", "7", "f", "T")
t16 = ("D", "O", "0", "B", "8", "Q", "q")
t17 = ("c", "a")
t18 = ("9", "J", "7", "f", "I")
t19 = ("C", "O", "D", "0", "6")
t20 = ("P", "F", "C")

tuple1 = (t11,t12,t13,t14,t15,t16,t17,t18,t19,t20)
```

I want iterate/loop on xlist1/tuple1 to get a new list/tuple in a special format. 
The target output-list/-tuple should be unique.

```
output = (["1C5e1Dc9CP"],["xC5e1Dc9CP"],["tC5e1Dc9CP"],["FC5e1Dc9CP"],["TC5e1Dc9CP"],
         ["1D5e1Dc9CP"],["165e1Dc9CP"],
         ["1C9e1Dc9CP"],["1CJe1Dc9CP"],["1CDe1Dc9CP"],
         ["1C5a1Dc9CP"],["1C5o1Dc9CP"],["1C5x1Dc9CP"],["1C5f1Dc9CP"],["1C5z1Dc9CP"],
         ...
         ["T6DzTqaI6C"])
```

Iterate about all indicies:

```
'1D5e1Dc9CP'    '1D5e1Dc9CP'    '1D9e1Dc9CP'    '1DJe1Dc9CP'    '1DDe1Dc9CP'    '1D5a1Dc9CP'    '1D5o1Dc9CP'    '1D5x1Dc9CP'    '1D5f1Dc9CP'    '1D5z1Dc9CP'    '1D5exDc9CP'    '1D5e7Dc9CP'    '1D5efDc9CP'    '1D5eTDc9CP'    '1D5e1Oc9CP'    '1D5e10c9CP'    '1D5e1Bc9CP'    '1D5e18c9CP'    '1D5e1Qc9CP'    '1D5e1qc9CP'    '1D5e1Da9CP'    '1D5e1DcJCP'    '1D5e1Dc7CP'    '1D5e1DcfCP'    '1D5e1DcICP'    '1D5e1Dc9OP'    '1D5e1Dc9DP'    '1D5e1Dc90P'    '1D5e1Dc96P'    '1D5e1Dc9CF'    '1D5e1Dc9CC'
'xD5exDc9CP'    'x65exDc9CP'    'xC9exDc9CP'    'xCJe1Dc9CP'    'xCDe1Dc9CP'    'xC5a1Dc9CP'    'xC5o1Dc9CP'    'xC5x1Dc9CP'    'xC5f1Dc9CP'    'xC5z1Dc9CP'    'xC5exDc9CP'    'xC5e7Dc9CP'    'xC5efDc9CP'    'xC5eTDc9CP'    'xC5e1Oc9CP'    'xC5e10c9CP'    'xC5e1Bc9CP'    'xC5e18c9CP'    'xC5e1Qc9CP'    'xC5e1Qc9CP'    'xC5e1Da9CP'    'xC5e1DcJCP'    'xC5e1Dc7CP'    'xC5e1DcfCP'    'xC5e1DcICP'    'xC5e1Dc9OP'    'xC5e1Dc9DP'    'xC5e1Dc90P'    'xC5e1Dc96P'    'xC5e1Dc9CF'    'xC5e1Dc9CC'
'TC5e1Dc9CP'    'TCJe1Dc9CP'    'TCDe1Dc9CP'    'TC5a1Dc9CP'    'TC5o1Dc9CP'    'TC5x1Dc9CP'    'TC5f1Dc9CP'    'TC5z1Dc9CP'    'TC5exDc9CP'    'TC5e7Dc9CP'    'TC5efDc9CP'    'TC5eTDc9CP'    'TC5e1Oc9CP'    'TC5e10c9CP'    'TC5e1Bc9CP'    'TC5e18c9CP'    'TC5e1Qc9CP'    'TC5e1qc9CP'    'TC5e1Da9CP'    'TC5e1DcJCP'    'TC5e1Dc7CP'    'TC5e1DcfCP'    'TC5e1DcICP'    'TC5e1Dc9OP'    'TC5e1Dc9DP'    'TC5e1Dc90P'    'TC5e1Dc96P'    'TC5e1Dc9CF'    'TC5e1Dc9CC'        
'TD5e1Dc9CP'    'TDJe1Dc9CP'    'TDDe1Dc9CP'    'TD5a1Dc9CP'    'TD5o1Dc9CP'    'TD5x1Dc9CP'    'TD5f1Dc9CP'    'TD5z1Dc9CP'    'TD5exDc9CP'    'TD5e7Dc9CP'    'TD5efDc9CP'    'TD5eTDc9CP'    'TD5e1Oc9CP'    'TD5e10c9CP'    'TD5e1Bc9CP'    'TD5e18c9CP'    'TD5e1Qc9CP'    'TD5e1qc9CP'    'TD5e1Da9CP'    'TD5e1DcJCP'    'TD5e1Dc7CP'    'TD5e1DcfCP'    'TD5e1DcICP'    'TD5e1Dc9OP'    'TD5e1Dc9DP'    'TD5e1Dc90P'    'TD5e1Dc96P'    'TD5e1Dc9CF'    'TD5e1Dc9CC'        
'T65e1Dc9CP'    'T6Je1Dc9CP'    'T6De1Dc9CP'    'T65a1Dc9CP'    'T65o1Dc9CP'    'T65x1Dc9CP'    'T65f1Dc9CP'    'T65z1Dc9CP'    'T65exDc9CP'    'T65e7Dc9CP'    'T65efDc9CP'    'T65eT6c9CP'    'T65e1Oc9CP'    'T65e10c9CP'    'T65e1Bc9CP'    'T65e18c9CP'    'T65e1Qc9CP'    'T65e1qc9CP'    'T65e1Da9CP'    'T65e1DcJCP'    'T65e1Dc7CP'    'T65e1DcfCP'    'T65e1DcICP'    'T65e1Dc9OP'    'T65e1Dc9DP'    'T65e1Dc90P'    'T65e1Dc96P'    'T65e1Dc9CF'    'T65e1Dc9CC'
```

Here I show the iteration algorithm with inidicies:

```
output = ([x11[0]+x12[0]+x13[0]+x14[0]+x15[0]+x16[0]+x17[0]+x18[0]+x19[0]+x20[0]], 
         # 1C5e1Dc9CP
          [x11[1]+x12[0]+x13[0]+x14[0]+x15[0]+x16[0]+x17[0]+x18[0]+x19[0]+x20[0]], 
         # xC5e1Dc9CP 
          [x11[2]+x12[0]+x13[0]+x14[0]+x15[0]+x16[0]+x17[0]+x18[0]+x19[0]+x20[0]], 
         # tC5e1Dc9CP
          [x11[3]+x12[0]+x13[0]+x14[0]+x15[0]+x16[0]+x17[0]+x18[0]+x19[0]+x20[0]], 
         # FC5e1Dc9CP
          [x11[4]+x12[0]+x13[0]+x14[0]+x15[0]+x16[0]+x17[0]+x18[0]+x19[0]+x20[0]], 
         # TC5e1Dc9CP

          [x11[0]+x12[1]+x13[0]+x14[0]+x15[0]+x16[0]+x17[0]+x18[0]+x19[0]+x20[0]], 
         # 1D5e1Dc9CP
          [x11[0]+x12[1]+x13[0]+x14[0]+x15[0]+x16[0]+x17[0]+x18[0]+x19[0]+x20[0]], 
         # 165e1Dc9CP

          [x11[0]+x12[0]+x13[1]+x14[0]+x15[0]+x16[0]+x17[0]+x18[0]+x19[0]+x20[0]], 
         # 1C9e1Dc9CP
          [x11[0]+x12[0]+x13[2]+x14[0]+x15[0]+x16[0]+x17[0]+x18[0]+x19[0]+x20[0]], 
         # 1CJe1Dc9CP
          [x11[0]+x12[0]+x13[3]+x14[0]+x15[0]+x16[0]+x17[0]+x18[0]+x19[0]+x20[0]], 
         # 1CDe1Dc9CP

          [x11[0]+x12[1]+x13[0]+x14[1]+x15[0]+x16[0]+x17[0]+x18[0]+x19[0]+x20[0]], 
         # 1C5a1Dc9CP
          [x11[0]+x12[1]+x13[0]+x14[2]+x15[0]+x16[0]+x17[0]+x18[0]+x19[0]+x20[0]], 
         # 1C5o1Dc9CP
          [x11[0]+x12[1]+x13[0]+x14[3]+x15[0]+x16[0]+x17[0]+x18[0]+x19[0]+x20[0]], 
         # 1C5x1Dc9CP
          [x11[0]+x12[1]+x13[0]+x14[4]+x15[0]+x16[0]+x17[0]+x18[0]+x19[0]+x20[0]], 
         # 1C5f1Dc9CP
          [x11[0]+x12[1]+x13[0]+x14[5]+x15[0]+x16[0]+x17[0]+x18[0]+x19[0]+x20[0]], 
         # 1C5z1Dc9CP
          ...
          [x11[4]+x12[2]+x13[3]+x14[5]+x15[4]+x16[6]+x17[1]+x18[5]+x19[4]+x20[2]]) 
         # T6DzTqaI6C
```

So, it is import that output-tuple/list are unique and have all the same length `== 10 chars`, (`len(xlist1)`) and always the direction
from x11 .. x20.

I've tried thinks like, but it doesn't solve it...

```
combs = functools.reduce(lambda x, y: list(itertools.combinations(xlist1, y)) + x, range(len(xlist1)+1), [])
for c in combs:
    print ("Combination:", c)
```

or

```
combs = list(itertools.combinations(tuple1, r=x))
permutations = list(itertools.permutations(xlist1, r=None)) # terminal killed it :/
```

Does anyone have  suggestions, ideas or solutions?

Comment: Shouldn't the last item in your output start with a `T`?

Comment: To make sure the output is unique you could use a set. Make sure you don't include the strings nested in lists as you have in the format above, because lists are unhashable so you can't add them to a set. Using set("1C5e1Dc9CP", "xC5e1Dc9CP" ... ) instead of (["1C5e1Dc9CP"], ["xC5e1Dc9CP"]...) would work I think.

Comment: As long as each sub-list has no duplicates, no combination drawn from them should get duplicated.

Comment: `x18` & `t18` have a duplicate `J`. Does it need to handle duplicates?

Comment: Your "iteration with indices" explicitly generates the same string twice, and the order needs to be explained.

Comment: I can generate the desired output in a formulaic manner with or without duplicates, but without clarification it's unclear which will solve the question.

Comment: @ScottHunter you are right. It schould start with a T.  've edited.

Comment: @TemporalWolf you are right. I've corrected it. Each char in any list of x11... x20 is unique.

Answer (score 1):

To get the full *product* of the lists, you want:

```
list(itertools.product(*tuple1))
```

which with your inputs will be 1.6M elements:

```
['1C5e1Dc9CP', '1C5e1Dc9CF', '1C5e1Dc9CC', '1C5e1Dc9OP', '1C5e1Dc9OF', 
 '1C5e1Dc9OC', '1C5e1Dc9DP', '1C5e1Dc9DF', '1C5e1Dc9DC', '1C5e1Dc90P' ...]
```

To chunk this, write a chunking function:

```
def chunker(gen, size):
    while True:
        lst = []
        for _ in range(size):
            lst.append(next(gen))
        yield lst

product_generator = itertools.product(*tuple1)
chunks = chunker(product_generator, 50000)
```

then you get each chunk via

```
chunk = next(chunks)
```

---

**Below** is the previous answer, which does not generate a complete product of the lists:

This generates a list and works correctly with duplicates for arbitrary lists where you want to iterate a single element across the whole base.

```
full = []
for piece_index in range(len(tuple1)):
    for inner_index in range(0 if piece_index == 0 else 1, len(tuple1[piece_index])):
        line = ""
        for index in range(len(tuple1)):
            line += tuple1[index][inner_index if piece_index == index else 0]
        full.append(line)
```

This works by going list by list, element by element, and building a string around that element. It also skips the first element in every list except the first, as that is just a duplicate of the first element.

- `piece_index` keep track of which sublist we're currently working on.
- `inner_index` keeps track of which element in that sublist we're currently building a string about
- `index` is which character in that string built around `tuple1[piece_index][inner_index]` we're currently on.

Result:

```
['1C5e1Dc9CP', 'xC5e1Dc9CP', 'tC5e1Dc9CP', 'fC5e1Dc9CP', 'TC5e1Dc9CP', 
 '1D5e1Dc9CP', '165e1Dc9CP', 
 '1C9e1Dc9CP', '1CJe1Dc9CP', '1CDe1Dc9CP', 
 '1C5a1Dc9CP', '1C5o1Dc9CP', '1C5x1Dc9CP', '1C5f1Dc9CP', '1C5z1Dc9CP', 
 '1C5exDc9CP', '1C5e7Dc9CP', '1C5efDc9CP', '1C5eTDc9CP', 
 '1C5e1Oc9CP', '1C5e10c9CP', '1C5e1Bc9CP', '1C5e18c9CP', '1C5e1Qc9CP', '1C5e1qc9CP', 
 '1C5e1Da9CP', 
 '1C5e1DcJCP', '1C5e1Dc7CP', '1C5e1DcfCP', '1C5e1DcICP', '1C5e1DcJCP', 
 '1C5e1Dc9OP', '1C5e1Dc9DP', '1C5e1Dc90P', '1C5e1Dc96P', 
 '1C5e1Dc9CF', '1C5e1Dc9CC']
```

If you want them as a tuple of  1 element lists, `full.append([line])` and adding a `full = tuple(full)` after the loops will make that change.

It's worth noting this **does** contain a duplicate (`'1C5e1DcJCP'`), as your source lists contain a duplicate: `t18 = ("9", "J", "7", "f", "I", "J")`

Comment: nice work. But I want to iterate about all indicies.

Comment: @Kris this generates exactly your expected output. If that isn't what you are looking for, please edit your question with revised information. I don't understand what you mean about iterate about all indices.

Comment: yes it did the ouput but without ...
         ["T6DzTqaI6C"]) and all other combinations between it. Sorry that I can't explain it so bad. But there have to been much more combinations. I post some more outputs on my question. I' ll try to explain it more exact. Thank you for your advice.

Comment: @Kris Is the order of the output relevant, or do you just need all combinations as described?

Comment: full = [ [x11,x12,x13,x14,x15,x16,x17,x18,x19,x20], [x11,x12,x13,x14,x15,x16,x17,x18,x19,x20], ....]

Comment: Does it matter that `'1C5e1Dc9CP'` comes before `"T6DzTqaI6C"` or is the final list order unimportant?

Comment: the order of each tuple in full have to be like this. full = [  [x11[0],x12[0],x13[0],x14[0],x15[0],x16[0],x17[0],x18[0],x19[0],x20[0]],... [x11[n],x12[n],x13[n],x14[n],x15[n],x16[n],x17[n],x18[n],x19[n],x20[n]] ], but order in sublist isn't important, it is only important that all combination will be in full and unique. I've posted some more combinations above, maybe it helps.

Comment: Does it matter that '1C5e1Dc9CP' comes before "T6DzTqaI6C" or is the final list order unimportant? It is unimportant,

Comment: @Kris tl;dr is you want `itertools.product()`

Comment: `itertools.product(x11,...,x22)` looks good. but with more sublists thread will be terminated.

Comment: because the output is huge. It's already 1.6m elements.

Comment: `keylist=tuple(itertools.islice(itertools.product(*keylist), 50000))` this is a workaround. How can I put outputs in multiple files? So that when 1st 50000 finished write in 1.csv and begin from 50001 to 100000 write to 2.csv and so on.

Comment: @Kris I added a function to chunk the output. You can then treat each chunk as a list.

Comment: Awesome. That's exactly what it supposed to do. Thank you very much!